# xcode 7.0.1 Auto Layout not appearing on simulator but appearing on preview and device

Tags: uiscrollview, autolayout, xcode7, simulator, preview

I add `autolayout` constraints to a `UIScrollView` and a `UIView`. The UIView is subview of Scrollview. This UIView appears in preview, but not on simulator.

I choose `w:Campect h:Regular` model in storyboard. Image Description:

[image]

When I configured UIView with the properties `w:Any h:Any`, the simulator can display UIView (yellow color one), but I don't know why.